# Local workstation as Mercurial server

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, windows-server-2008

I am trying to follow the instructions posted [here](http://www.nimblecoder.com/blog/archive/2010/01/21/using-mercurial-with-virtual-machines.aspx)  but am getting stuck at step 3.  After setting up my local workstation to serve the Repository; I cannot clone it from my server.  When I run the following command

```
hg clone http://COMPUTER-XXXXX.hsd1.va.comcast.net:8000/
```

I receive

```
abort: error: getaddrinfo failed
```

What am I missing?  I am running TortoiseHg on my Windows XP laptop and a Server 2008 set up on a VM.  Thanks.

Comment: Try browsing to the same URL `http://COMPUTER-XXXXX.hsd1.va.comcast.net:8000/` in a browser.  If it works, hg will serve up a basic interface to browse the remote repo.  It may still fail, but the error message might be more informative.

Comment: I can only navigate on my localhost through the browser; no informative messages are displayed when I try to load through a browser (I tried a few machines) both IP and Machine name were used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing 'HTTPS' to 'HTTP'.

Also check your proxy settings. If you're behind a corporate firewall, you may need to go into Global Settings --> Proxy and copy your proxy server address and port into the Host field.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure your server is able to reach the work station by name?  Try this on the command line:

```
ping COMPUTER-XXXXX.hsd1.va.comcast.net
```

It looks like the DNS lookup is failing, but that's just a guess.

Perhaps try cloning by IP?

```
hg clone http://192.168.1.134:8000
```

or whatever the IP of your desktop is?

(also there's no trailing period after your clone command, right?)

Comment: I can ping my machine both by ip and name (I also renamed it to a simpler machine name).

Cloning by IP doesn't do the trick either.

Comment: Are you running windows firewall on your desktop machine?  If so, you'll have to open up port 8000.

Answer (score 2):

Reading this issue: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/bts/issue535 it seems that other people had problems with their http proxy settings on windows. Could you try editing the proxy settings in IE and set "direct connect to the internet" (or something like that) instead, to see if this works around your problem ? Then as someone suggested it might be a firewall problem: you might want to try to "telnet < machine > 8000" to see if the port is blocked somewhere or not (but the error messages looks more like a name resolution problem..).

Hope it'll help.

Comment: Turns out work had an extra firewall layer blocking the port.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem but i was connecting to CVS through VPN and VPn was not active on my machine resulted in this error....once i started VPN, it went through